# Displaying data in JComboBox using value from another JComboBox

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jcombobox

I have one JComboBox which displaying account numbers from MYSQL Database table
its looks like this:

```
    private void FillAcountComboBox(){
    try{
        String value = Login_TextField.getText();
        String sql = "select * from Acount where User_Number = '" +value+ "'";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
            String AN = rs.getString("Acount_Number");
            Acount_ComboBox.addItem(AN);
        }

    }catch(Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

As I said. This works fine and I know there are 3 numbers (858960647,881674907,34222865) so these 3 numbers are in Acount_ComboBox

However I wanted to do another JComboBox (Order_ComboBox) which will show those numbers which aren't selected in Acount_ComboBox.

So basically if Acount_ComboBox will have selected number 858960647 the Order_ComboBox will display the 881674907 and 34222865

So if I try this SQL command:

```
String sql = "SELECT Acount_Number FROM Acount Where Acount_Number != 858960647"
```

it works just fine and Order_ComboBox displays 881674907 and 34222865

but if I wanted to "upgrade" Order_ComboBox to reading value from Acount_ComboBox it display again all three numbers which is wrong. :(

This is Order_ComboBox's "upgraded" code:

```
private void FillOrderComboBox(){
    try{
        String value2 = Acount_ComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString(); 
        String sql = "SELECT Acount_Number FROM Acount Where Acount_Number != '" +value2+ "'";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
            String AN2 = rs.getString("Acount_Number");
            Order_ComboBox.addItem(AN2);
        }

    }catch(Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

So I wondering where I did my mistake, so if someone willing to give me helping hand and show me that mistake I will be happy :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is likely **when** you call this `FillOrderComboBox(...)` method (which should be renamed `fillOrderComboBox(...)`). If you call it **before** the user has had a chance to select anything, then it makes sense that all 3 numbers will be placed in the order combo box. Best to have this code in the ActionListener that responds to the user making the initial selection. Also, why go back to the database at all? Why not instead simply iterate through the first JComboBox's model, using each item *unless* it was selected?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes in the query to get the numbers which are not selected.